# Finding first occurrence of even numbers

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [20, 21, 333, 55, 444, 1000, 900, 44,100, 200, 100],
        'b': [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6]
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 2 | x |
| 1 | 21 | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 333 | 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 55 | 4 | x |
| 4 | 444 | 4 | NaN |
| 5 | 1000 | 4 | NaN |
| 6 | 900 | 4 | NaN |
| 7 | 44 | 3 | NaN |
| 8 | 100 | 2 | x |
| 9 | 200 | 2 | NaN |
| 10 | 100 | 6 | x |

I want to create column `c` which marks the first occurrence of an even number. It does not matter whether the even number is repeated consecutively or not. First occurrence is what I want.

For example the first row is marked because it is the first occurrence of 2 in column `b`. And the streak of 2 ends. Accordingly, that is why the first 4 is marked.

I tried this code:

```
def finding_first_even_number(df):
    mask = (df.b % 2 == 0)
    df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'
    return df

df = df.groupby('b').apply(finding_first_even_number)
```

But it does not give me the output that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

```
# counter to identify different blocks of
# consecutive rows having same value in b
b = df['b'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

# boolean mask to identify if the value is even
# and its the first occurrence in block
mask = (df['b'] % 2 == 0) & ~b.duplicated()

# boolean indexing to flag the True values to `x`
df.loc[mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

#### Result

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 2 | x |
| 1 | 21 | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 333 | 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 55 | 4 | x |
| 4 | 444 | 4 | NaN |
| 5 | 1000 | 4 | NaN |
| 6 | 900 | 4 | NaN |
| 7 | 44 | 3 | NaN |
| 8 | 100 | 2 | x |
| 9 | 200 | 2 | NaN |
| 10 | 100 | 6 | x |

Answer (score 0):

```
col1=df['b'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
col2=df.groupby(col1,group_keys=False).apply(lambda dd:dd.head(1).assign(col='x' if dd['b'].max()%2==0 else np.NaN).col)
df.assign(c=col2)
```

out：

```
     a  b    c
0     20  2    x
1     21  2  NaN
2    333  2  NaN
3     55  4    x
4    444  4  NaN
5   1000  4  NaN
6    900  4  NaN
7     44  3    x
8    100  2    x
9    200  2  NaN
10   100  6    x
```